# shinylive pyodide cannot install shiny package for a quarto dashboard

Tags: python, quarto, py-shinylive

I am attempting to embed a shinylive app in a quarto dashboard. App will let the user selectize filter a categorical variable in a seaborn barplot.

However, I receive the following error in the panel where the app *should* appear:

```
Error starting app!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<exec>", line 362, in _start_app
ModuleNotFoundError: The module 'shiny' is included in the Pyodide distribution, but it is not installed.
You can install it by calling:
  await micropip.install("shiny") in Python, or
  await pyodide.loadPackage("shiny") in JavaScript
See https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/loading-packages.html for more details.
```

Currently, in my **`_quarto.yml`**

```
project:
  type: website
  output-dir: public

website:
  title: "title"
  navbar:
    left:
      - href: index.qmd
        text: Home
      - href: about.qmd
        text: About

format: dashboard

filters:
  - shinylive

jupyter: python3
```

and my **`index.qmd`**

````
```{python py_load_deps}
#| echo: false

# data munging & viz
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.express as px
```

## Row

Some explainer text.

## Row

```{shinylive-python}
#| standalone: true

#| title: Grouped Bar Plot - NOV 2023

## file: dat/filename.xlsx

from shiny import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from pathlib import Path
    
# UI
app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.input_select(
        "select_items",
        "select items:",
        dat().item.unique().tolist(),
        multiple = True
    ),
    ui.output_plot("plot")
)

# server
def server(input, output, session):
    @reactive.calc
    def dat():
        v_path = Path(__file__).parent.resolve() / "dat/filename.xlsx"
        dict_types = {"item": str, "value": np.float64, "value2": np.float64}
        df_summary = pd.read_excel(v_path, sheet_name="sheet_name", usecols="A:D", dtype=dict_types)
        df_summary_grp = df_summary.melt(id_vars='item', value_vars=['value1', 'value2'])
        df_summary_grp = df_summary_grp.reset_index()

        return df_summary_grp

    @reactive.calc
    def items():
        return dat().item.unique().tolist()

    @output
    @render.plot(alt="Grouped Bar of Items")
    def plot():
        g_ax_item_grp = sns.barplot(y='item', x='values', hue='variable', data=dat().loc[dat()[['item']].isin[input.select_item()]])
        g_ax_item_grp.set_xlabel(None)
        sns.move_legend(g_ax_item_grp, loc="lower center", bbox_to_anchor=(-.4,-.3), ncol=2, title=None, frameon=False)
        return g_ax_item_grp

# app
app = App(app_ui, server)

```
````

I have verified that all packages are installed, and have tried adding `micropip.install('shiny')` to the shinylive block as specified in the error message, but to no avail.

Thanks in advance for any help!